# jQuery Tools Scrollable Dots

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery Tools Scrollable to create what's on the jQuery Tools chaining example (see link below).  I'm attempting to fix an issue with the page indicator dots.  In the example,  clicking the right arrow when the page indicator is on the third dot causes a delay, not highlighting the first dot until the slides have come back around.  The same issue happens when clicking left when the page indicator is on the first dot.  Has anyone come across a fix for this problem?

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was examining the code and the equation to calculate the page position is dividing based on getConf().size.  This size is 1 over the needed index.  Here's the fix.  Open jquery.tools.js, find fn.navigator.  Now look for onBeforeSeek. Add this if statement you see below.

```
b.onBeforeSeek(function(a, b) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                    var c = (b / j) , d = l().eq(c);

                    if ((b / j) == l().length){
                        c = 0;
                        d = l().eq(c);
                    }

                    d.length && l().removeClass(h).eq(c).addClass(h);
            }, 0)
        })
```

This is a global change and there may be a better way to go about this without modifying the jquery.tools file

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the "Chaining plugins" demo on that page.

You can rig this by applying the "active" class to the first dot anchor tag via the `onBeforeSeek` event. So, using that demo, something like this should do it:

```
$("#chained").scrollable({circular: true, mousewheel: true}).navigator();

var scroller = $('#chained').data('scrollable'),
    count = scroller.getItems().length;

scroller.onBeforeSeek(function(event, index) {
  if ( index == count ) $('div.navi').find('a').removeClass('active').eq(0).addClass('active');
}
```

NOTE: Untested.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  It's currently working, modified a bit.  Now the only problem I'm having is that .navi classes in all my scrollable instances are being targeted instead of just the one I'm using.  I've tried changing it to (".navi", this) but that wasn't working.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, just use a container div for context: `$('#container').find('.navi').find('a')...`

Comment: Ahhh I see.  Unfortunately I would have to set a unique ID for each instance of scrollable as this is used globally throughout many pages, all of which utilizing scrollable.   I'll post my working code once done.  
Note:  I'm applying these IDs to SharePoint Web Parts.

.attr("id","scroll" + scrollCount);

Comment: Actually, The scroller variable should have DOM info that you can use to select the closest .navi.